# What's the best tweening package for Haxe?

Tags: haxe

I'm looking for a tweening library similar to TweenMax in functionality. What's the best one around currently? The only real library I've found is FEffects and have hit a few misc bugs with it. Ideally, I am looking for a tweening utilities that favors performance.

Comment: I'm not totally sure if this question makes sense for SO.  I'm not flagging it, because both of you (@Gama11 and @JonathanDunlap) are more experienced than myself, but this does seem to me to be possibly an opinion based recommendation type question, which is classically (I think) not encouraged.

Answer (score 2):

GtweenHx http://code.google.com/p/gtweenhx/  and Actuate http://code.google.com/p/actuate/ would be my number 1 and 2 choices.  I don't know how they fare performance-wise but they are easy to use.  GtweenHx is a port of Grants Skinner's Gtween library and is Actuate is equally as straightforward to use.

Answer (score 0):

[feffects](http://haxe.org/com/libs/feffects) is good with cross platform ( as in not NME ) other wise use actuate.